# How do you say 7/7?

Tags: pronunciation

We have several service agreements, but we're not sure how you actually say `7/7`. A `7/7` service agreement means support every day (even weekends), during business hours.

Do you just call it `seven/seven` like `24/7` or is there a different way of saying it?

Comment: It's more in the French speaking world (Ca,Be, Fr) that you'd use 24/24 or 7/7 to mean 7 days a week or 24 hours a day. In English you'd simply say "open 24 hours" or "open 7 days".

Comment: If you preceded “7/7” with “[9 to 5 support](https://www.telcobridges.com/support/tb-support#9%20to%205%20Support)” (“9 to 5 support, 7/7”) it would probably be understood as “9 to 5 support, seven days a week,” but I think “9 to 5 support, 365/365” would avoid a potentially confusing (and negative) comparison with the well-known “24/7” (and if you’re actually promising to be available “7/7” during those hours then you’re also promising to be available “365/365” during those hours).

Comment: Regardless, you would, as you suggested, just pronounce it "seven[/]seven," like "24/7."

Comment: I heard of "9-5/365", but never "7/7".

Comment: Would it not be simpler to say "seven-day support"?

Comment: @TimWard, that's what we're trying to find out :P We have `24/7 support (24/7), 7 days a week during business hours(7/7), 5 days a week during business hours(5/7) and next business day( NB)`. We've upgraded our telephone system and it's the first time we're actually saying it out loud.

Comment: @P.Obertelli, indeed, we're set in Belgium :)

Comment: Using "7/7" is not common in most of the US.  "24/7" is about the only such idiom that is familiar.

Comment: Sometimes things are better off not said, especially if the whole reason for saying it a different way is to marketize it. If you truly have business hours every day of the week, soon enough, people will know and you won't have to tell them. I think from a call center message perspective, it would better to just say the facts: "Our support hours are 9am to 5pm Eastern time (or whatever), every day." I agree with everyone who has already said that "7/7" is not an expression anyone would recognize or understand.

Comment: In any event, someone in the US would be apt to read "7/7" as "seven sevenths".

Comment: What @P.Obertelli said. "*Sept sur sept*" is common in French. In the US you would just say "*seven days a week*" or "*every day of the week*".

Answer (score 3):

For a shop, the sign on the outside would normally say either "Open 7 days a week" or "Open every day".

I can't think of a commonly used shorthand way to say it (based on my own experience in the UK).

Answer (score 2):

I have started to hear 7/7 (pronounced as **seven seven**) used in UK english and have readily taken it to mean seven out of seven days. When written as 7/7 I would not expect misunderstanding. The only exception to this that I can see is that if a sign outside a shop displayed this e.g. 7/11, it might be taken to mean hours of opening. In these circumstances, 'Open 7 Days' would be preferable.

Comment: The only context I have heard 7/7 used in is https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/7_July_2005_London_bombings

Comment: That is certainly a confusion that had not crossed my mind in replying. However, I have still heard the phrase on occasions to reflect 'every day.'

Answer (score 1):

I've never encountered that expression here (US, Ohio) but in general a fraction *X/Y* (that isn't subdividing a unit) is read "X of Y."  In this case, I'd find "7 of 7" support a fairly easy concept to comprehend, especially if there are other service plans like 5/7 or 3/7 (five days a week, or three days a week).  I wouldn't treat it as a known idiom, however, you'd need to introduce it before using it.

One additional consideration --if you're using both "24/7" and "7/7" as stock phrases, you're switching the units of the first number (from hours to days), which is confusing.

Answer (score 1):

**Common phrases regarding shop or service availability:**

---

**Written:** Available 24/7

**Verbal:** Available twenty four seven

---

**Written:** Available 24hrs

**Verbal:** Available twenty four hours

---

**Written:** Open 7 Days

**Verbal:** Open seven days

---

**Written:** Open 7 Days a week

**Verbal:** Open seven days a week

---

**Written:** Open 365 days

**Verbal:** Open three hundred and sixty five days / Open three sixty five days

---

**Written:** Open 365 days a year

**Verbal:** Open three hundred and sixty five days a year

---

I haven't seen the term **7/7** used, but given that its form is similar to **24/7** I'd suggest that 'seven seven' should be used.

I would suggest that **7 days** would be a better term to use over **7/7** though  - it's more explicit that it's referring to days a week and it's one less syllable. I don't see what **7/7** confers over **7 days** or **24/7**, except for being a cutesy variant of **24/7**.

Comment: I'm not sure which one they chose in the end (either 7/7 or 7 days a week), it just didn't sound right to anyone to say 7/7 so we assumed we were doing it wrong :P

Comment: @CustomX '7 days' is far more common.

Answer (score -1):

There's no such thing as 7/7 in these terms.  What would the other 7 represent?  Are you saying 7 hours a day, 7 days a week?  That's not something people say.

What would be understood is 7/365, which means 7 days a week, 365 days a year, or 7/364, which means 7 days a week, 364 days a year (every day but Christmas).

Comment: Oh, didn't know that. So support each day between 9AM and 5PM isn't 7/7, but translates to `7 days a week, during business hours`?

Comment: @CustomX : 9am to 5pm is 8 hours.  You might be able to write 8/7/365 and have it understood, but I've never seen it.  It's certain that 7/7 wouldn't be understood and probably not 8/7 either.