# Implied Prepositions?

Tags: prepositions, adjectives, adverbs

I'm having trouble with some parts of speech in this sentence in order to diagram it:

*In the past, working took up most people's time six days a week.*

The part I am having trouble understanding is "six days a week."  I can figure it out if I add in some prepositions, turning the sentence into:  "In the past, working took up most people's time *for* six days *in* a week."  How does the last part function in the sentence?  What word(s) do they modify?  Do I add in the prepositions?

Answer (score 1):

The phrase "six days a week" is common in English speech and writing.

You may think of it as "six days of a week," but that's far less common and idiomatic.  The following are all standard:

*He works out three days a week.*

*The store is open five days a week.*

*The store is open every day of the week except Saturday.*

Look at [How do you say 7/7?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/299099/how-do-you-say-7-7/299101#299101) for more discussion about this.

I think "six days a week" modifies the phrasal verb "took up," which has the object "time," but I could have that wrong.